# How to set onChange Event on comboBox at runtime using a procedure inside another procedure?

Tags: delphi, combobox

I have a dynamic code which It create a comboBox into a StringGrid Cell and this combo is created at runtime and I should set onChange Event for it. 
I'm using this code bellow, but this code raise a exception , someone can help-me to become my comboBoxOnChange method in a TNotifyEvent ?

```
procedure TForm1.gridSelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean);
var
  R: TRect;
  combo : TComboBox;
   procedure comboBoxOnChange(Sender: TObject);
   begin
      combo.Visible := false;
      combo.Free;
   end;
begin
  combo          := TComboBox.Create(self);
  combo.Parent   := self;
  //[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(57): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'
  combo.OnChange := comboBoxOnChange;

  combo.Items.Add('Item1');
  combo.Items.Add('Item2');
  combo.Items.Add('Item3');
  combo.Items.Add('Item4');
  combo.Items.Add('Item5');
  combo.Items.Add('Item6');
  combo.Items.Add('Item7');
  combo.Items.Add('Item8');
  combo.Items.Add('Item9');
  combo.Items.Add('Item10');

    R         := Grid.CellRect(ACol, ARow);
    R.Left    := R.Left   + grid.Left;
    R.Right   := R.Right  + grid.Left;
    R.Top     := R.Top    + grid.Top;
    R.Bottom  := R.Bottom + grid.Top;

    combo.Left := R.Left + 1;
    combo.Top := R.Top + 1;
    combo.Width := (R.Right + 1) - R.Left;
    combo.Height := (R.Bottom + 1) - R.Top;
    combo.Visible := True;
    combo.SetFocus;
    CanSelect := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any non-class-method procedure as an event handler if you declare and fill out a `TMethod` record manually and then type-cast it when assigning it to the target event.  Also, not being a member of a class means the hidden `Self` parameter is missing, so you have to declare it explicitly.

In the case of a nested procedure, this approach will work fine as long as the procedure does not try to access anything from its containing procedure, since those variables will not be in scope anymore when the event is actually triggered.

With that said, the bigger problem is that a control cannot `Free()` itself from inside one of its own events, otherwise you will get an AccessViolation error.  This is because the RTL still needs access to the object after the event handler exits.  So you have to delay calling `Free()` until after the event handler exits, such as by posting a custom window message with `PostMessage()` so it goes through the message queue.

Try this:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //...
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    //...
  end;
```

```
const
  APPWM_FREE_OBJECT = WM_APP + 100;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = APPWM_FREE_OBJECT then
    TObject(Message.LParam).Free
  else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.gridSelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; var CanSelect: Boolean);
var
  combo : TComboBox;
  M: TMethod;
  //...

  procedure comboBoxOnChange(Self: Pointer; Sender: TObject);
  begin
    TComboBox(Sender).Visible := false;
    //combo.Free;
    PostMessage(Form1.Handle, APPWM_FREE_OBJECT, 0, LPARAM(Sender));
  end;

begin
  combo          := TComboBox.Create(Self);
  combo.Parent   := Self;
  //...

  M.Code := Addr(comboBoxOnChange);
  M.Data := combo;
  combo.OnChange := TNotifyEvent(M);

  CanSelect := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

One can't use nested procedure as a eventhandler, you have to make it to a method of the form:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(...)
    private
      procedure comboBoxOnChange(Sender: TObject);
      ...
  end

procedure TForm1.comboBoxOnChange(Sender: TObject);
var combo : TComboBox;
begin
  combo := Sender as TComboBox;
  combo.Visible := false;
  combo.Free;
end;
```

Comment: You can use non-method procedures as event handlers if you declare and fill out a `TMethod` record manually and then type-cast it when assigning it to the event.

Comment: IMO not worth the trouble, unless you have really good reason to do it. But your point about freeing the control in it's eventhandler is a good one!

Comment: `TMethod` does have its uses, for instance assigning event handlers in unit tests and console apps.